# Leaking de memória em PHP

Tags: php, memória, gerenciamento-de-memória, doctrine, memory-leaks

*Leaking* de memória ou *memory leaky* ocorre quando um programa de computador faz o mau gerenciamento de alocação da memória de tal forma que a memória que não é mais necessária não é liberada.

Eu gostaria de entender como o *leaking* de memória pode ocorrer no PHP?

Como eu poderia "debugar" para corrigir vazamentos de memória?

A questão é referente ao uso do ORM Doctrine que está implicando em um alto consumo/manipulação de dados em memória. Transformando alguns processos em tarefas lentas e pesadas e, em alguns casos, falta memória para concluir a requisição, provocando o corte da mesma ou lentidão generalizada por consumo demasiado de recursos de máquina.

Caso alguém tenha alguma experiência sobre *memory-leak* no uso do Doctrine também ira ajudar.

Comment: O que já está escrito em PHP você não vai resolver o problema de memory-leak, como explicado já em respostas, você pode depurar memory-leak usando um programa chamado valgrind, sobre o Doctrine o problema de ter processos e tarefas lentas deve estar nas consultas que você está fazendo, tente otimizar a query usando native query quando necessário, reveja o uso de caches e também os seus relacionamentos. O problema na maioria das vezes não está na linguagem, mas no mal uso dela pelo programador.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP essencialmente não tem vazamento de memória porque ela trabalha com memória gerenciada pela linguagem através de um coletor de lixo baseado em [contagem de referência](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) com [coleta adicional de ciclos](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php), então o vazamento só pode ocorrer se tiver um *bug* nele ou o coletor de ciclos está desligado. Veja [`zend.enable-gc`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.zend.enable-gc), [`gc_enable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) e [`gc_collect_cycles()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php).

Não é simples criar ciclos. Se está fazendo isso tem grande chance de estar com um *design* confuso demais.

Mais ainda, em condições normais de uso do PHP não é nem para ter memória retida por tempo exagerado já que *scripts* rodam por muito pouco tempo, então na prática se nem tivesse um coletor de lixo faria pouca diferença já que pouco depois a memória será liberada integralmente.

Se o tal do Doctrine faz algo que está causando problemas reporte isso aos criadores ou use algo que não tenha um problema tão sério.

Se você está retendo muita memória tem que analisar o código, não tem uma fórmula mágica que diz olha em tal lugar e verá o vazamento. Toda potencial alocação pode estar retendo memória. Mas retenção não é vazamento.

Pode estar retendo informação por tempo demais por ter deixado algum recurso que usa memória não gerenciada aberto por tempo demais. Toda vez que usa um recurso externo, como um arquivo, banco de dados, rede, ou outro tipo de serviço precisa fechá-lo. Porém mesmo isso não é para causar problema porque no momento que a variável que mantém esse recurso aberto sai de escopo ele é liberado automaticamente ou pela contagem de referência ou pelo coletor de ciclos. E se tudo isto falhar será fechado no final do *script*.

Pode ser que esteja mantendo alguma variável mais tempo do que deveria.

Talvez esteja apenas carregando coisas demais na memória. Tem que analisar o código e ir cercando onde faz grandes cargas de memória e ver se dá para carregar menos ou carregar aos poucos.

[Leia mais sobre o GC](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.performance-considerations.php).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

É muito comum isso acontecer quando é feito uma consulta no banco de dados e esta não é fechada, mantendo ela aberta consome memória e tráfego na rede.

Uma solução no banco de dados mysql é usar:

```
mysqli_close($nome_da conexão);
```

Também pode ser evitada corrigindo erros de programação e simplificando o código. Evitando criar loops dentro de loop.